# Printooth Error doesn't print image Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android

I'm trying to print my Scroll View layout to my bluetooth printer using Printooth. I try to convert the layout to Bitmap using getBitmapFromView() Method and print using  this

```
printables.add(new ImagePrintable.Builder(b).build());
          printing.print(printables);
```

But when i try to print it, the app doesnt do anything and have this error, 
Can anybody help me solve this ?:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mazenrashed.printooth.utilities.Printing.print(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference
```

This is the code:

```
private void takeScreenShot() {

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ScreenShot/");

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        boolean success = folder.mkdir();
    }

    path = folder.getAbsolutePath();
    path = path + "/" + file_name + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf";

    // List<Integer> hights = new ArrayList<>();
    View u = findViewById(R.id.scroll);

    NestedScrollView z = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();

    Log.e("totalHeight--", "" + totalHeight);
    Log.e("totalWidth--", "" + totalWidth);

    //Save bitmap
    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ScreenShot/";
    File file = new File(extr);
    if (!file.exists())
        file.mkdir();
    fileName = file_name + ".jpg";
    myPath = new File(extr, fileName);
    imagesUri = myPath.getPath();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    b = getBitmapFromView(u, totalHeight, totalWidth);

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   // createPdf();
    final ArrayList<Printable> printables = new ArrayList<>();
      printables.add(new ImagePrintable.Builder(b).build());
      printing.print(printables);
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int totalHeight, int totalWidth) {

    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth, totalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    toGrayscale(returnedBitmap);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
public static Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap srcImage) {

    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcImage.getWidth(),
            srcImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    canvas.drawBitmap(srcImage, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmpGrayscale;
}
```

this is my Scroll view layout that i want to print :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
printing.print(printables);
```

to

```
Printooth.INSTANCE.printer().print(printables);
```